# Create an image in specific position when button is pressed in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, imageview

Hello guys I figured out how to get x and y coordinates when button is touched, whit something like this

```
        area1.setOnTouchListener {
            _, event ->
        val x = event.x
        val y = event.y
        chipPortiere.text= x.toString()
        chipData.text = y.toString()

        true
    }
```

However I can't figure out how to create an Image in those coordinates, thank you everyone